# Розкрутка чи розкручування сайту?

Tags: вживання-слів, росіянізм, калька, віддієслівні-іменники

Один із багатьох прикладів з інтернету:

> Вам потрібно замовити розкрутку і просування сайту якщо Ви прагнете:
>
> 1. підвищити позицію вашого сайту у видачі пошукових системи
> 2. підвищити відвідуваність свого сайту за запитами, що цікавлять Вас

[Розкрутка сайтів](http://webstudio2u.net/ua/promotion.html)

СУМ містить спільнокореневе

РОЗКРУЧУВАТИ

5. перен., розм. Розпочинати якусь справу, розвивати якусь діяльність і т. ін.

http://translate.meta.ua/ дає слово **розкручування**

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozkruchuvaty)

Як мені відомо, для УМ словотвори із суфіксом -ка невластиві, але дуже продуктивні через калькування з рос.

Цікаво, що **оборудка** - нормальне укр. слово. А от **розкрутка**?

Comment: Слово «розкрутка» [цілком вживається](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=розкрутка). Але воно є радше жаргонізмом/професіоналізмом (наприклад, згадується в цій ролі у [журналі «Мовознавство» 2003 року](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22жаргонізмів+і+професіоналізмів%22+%22розкрутка%22)), ніж нейтральною лексикою — принаймні у цьому значенні. Нормативно це називається [«пошукова оптимізація»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Оптимізація_для_пошукових_систем).

Comment: @Sasha sxoge na ⅓ vidpovidi, budjte obačni cčodo _napiv vidpovidi_. /g

Comment: @Follower, ну, «⅓ відповіді»≠«відповідь». Тому мені й не подобається оце «не пишіть (напів)відповіді у коментарях», бо, якби таке правило було б, воно створювало б умови, що перешкоджали б збиранню відповіді по дуже маленьких частинах різними людьми. Якби при цьому не було жорстких вимог щодо якості готової відповіді, можна було б такі фрагменти робити відповідями — а так, наче, і у відповіді не можна, і в коменти «не можна».

Comment: @Sasha spokijnice, to buw **/g**art.

Answer (score 2):

Пропоную варіант "просування сайту":

В СУМі є слово "[просування](http://sum.in.ua/s/prosuvannja)" та "[просовувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/prosovuvaty)":

> //  перен. Сприяти розвиткові, поступальному рухові і т. ін.

Крім того, зустрічаємо цей варіант на Вікіпедії - стаття "[Просування сайту](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83)", а також "[Просування (маркетинг)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3))". А також зверніть увагу на літературні джерела:

*Ігор Ашманов, Андрій Іванов. Оптимізація і **просування сайтів** в пошукових системах.*